# Spatie Laravel ID change to own UUID?

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

Im using SQL uuid_short to build my laravel. is it possible to apply uuid to spaite laravel?

```
Schema::create($tableNames['permissions'], function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->bigIncrements('id');
  $table->string('permissions_uuid'); //(add by myself)
  $table->string('name');
  $table->string('guard_name');
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

//My Uuid creation

```
DB::selectOne(DB::raw('select uuid_short() as uuid'))->uuid
```

Comment: why would you even need/want to do that?

Comment: its because i need to intergrade with my old system